# Redraw/refresh layout after changing Activity's theme/style

Tags: java, android

I have two themes defined in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo"></style>

<style name="AppLightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

This is how I set the theme of an activity:

```
protected void changeTheme(boolean dark) {
    if (dark) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppLightTheme);
    }
}
```

Now after I change the theme, only the background stays the same UNTIL I open a different layout and go back. I'm using a DrawerLayout so I basically switch between layouts.

How can I re-draw it or kind of refresh it?

This is all I've tried that didn't do anything:

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);
vg.invalidate();
```

.

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); //this one is obvious, had to include so you don't try this unnecesarry.. code
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).refreshDrawableState();
```

.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
```

.

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

.

```
myLayout.invalidate();
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) to recreate your activity and cause all Views to be recreated with the new theme.

```
protected void changeTheme(boolean dark) {
  if (dark) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
  } else {
    setTheme(R.style.AppLightTheme);
  }
  recreate();
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure to set your theme again before you call `setContentView`

Comment: Oh my.. I was doing setTheme above everything in onCreate xD
Thank you so much! Works like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0):

recreate() is ok if your app is only targeting SDK level 11 and above.
When need to restart an activity, you can use following code.

```
Bundle temp_bundle = new Bundle();
onSaveInstanceState(temp_bundle);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle", temp_bundle);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and in onCreate...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (getIntent().hasExtra("bundle") && savedInstanceState==null){
    savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("bundle");
}

//add code for theme

switch(theme)
{
case LIGHT:
    setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
    theme = LIGHT;
    break;
case BLACK:
    setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
    theme = BLACK;
    break;

default:
}
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//code
}
```

I've included code for switching theme. Here, 'theme' is a string variable.

Comment: that didnt change the theme. it only reopened.